# Android onTouch doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I have the following code that should do this: I have an ImageView object with background and a bitmap that represents a figure. Figure has it's rectangle where I draw it. When I touch the ImageView object, if I touch somewhere in the figure rectangle, I'm going to "pick up" the figure and move it while the finger moves, and drop it when I put my finger up. If I touch the screen anywhere outside the figure rectangle, I should do nothing - ignore the touch completely. My code looks like this:

```
  protected int lastx, lasty;
  protected MyImageView iv;

  ...

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch(event.getActionMasked())
       {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastx = (int)event.getX();
            lasty = (int)event.getY();
            if(!iv.inFigure((int)lastx, (int)lasty))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            iv.move(x - lastx, y - lasty);
            lastx = x;
            lasty = y;

            return true;

        default:
        {

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            iv.move(x - lastx, y - lasty);
            lastx = x;
            lasty = y;

            return true;
        }

      }
   }
```

Problem is, wherever I touch the screen figure starts moving, not only when I touch it's rectangle.
iv.inFigure(x,y) works fine, the proof is that this code works when I add this boolean variable:

```
  protected int lastx, lasty;
  protected MyImageView iv;
  protected boolean startMoving = false;

  ...

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       switch(event.getActionMasked())
       {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            lastx = (int)event.getX();
            lasty = (int)event.getY();
            if(!iv.inFigure((int)lastx, (int)lasty))
                {
                    startMoving = false;
                    return false;
                }
            else
            {
                startMoving = true;
                return true;
            }


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

          if(startMoving)
            {
               int x = (int) event.getX();
               int y = (int) event.getY();
               iv.move(x - lastx, y - lasty);
               lastx = x;
               lasty = y;
            }
            return true;

        default:
        {
           if(startMoving)
            {
               int x = (int) event.getX();
               int y = (int) event.getY();
               iv.move(x - lastx, y - lasty);
               lastx = x;
               lasty = y;
            }
            return true;
        }

      }
   }
```

As far as I know, the first code should work without adding additional flag, because ACTION_MOVE is ignored when ACTION_DOWN returns false, until we detect ACTION_DOWN again and return true. So, when I touch the screen somewhere where inFigure will return false I should be ignoring any move started with that touch, but still, my figure moves. With startMoving variable and additional checks everything works fine. But I don't want to use that variable, I want to know why my code doesn't work without it. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never return `true` on default case (unless you really have to).
You should better return something like:

```
return super.onTouch(event);
```

As far as I understand what you are trying to achieve, you only need to listen for `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL`

Comment: When I do that or return false, my program crashes the first time I pick my finger up from the screen. And it still moves, wherever I touch.

Comment: It crashes? So, show me the error.  BTW, your default block should be empty. What are you trying to achieve inside this block ?

Comment: I've found the problem. In my layout, I left the onClick attribute for MyImageView, and never implemented it. It causes the program to crash when i return false in default and now that I deleted it, it works even when I return true. I guess it tried to perform click at some point and it crashed. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You are right, that code is unnecessary but it doesn't do the harm. I thought maybe last move before ACTION_UP might not be registered, so I wanted to move figure once again just in case.